# Kotlin, remove duplicates from Linkedlist : smart cast is impossible

Tags: kotlin, linked-list

I implemented a LinkedList in kotlin and wrote a method to remove duplicates from it:

```
class Node (value:Int) {
    var value = value
    var next:Node? = null

fun addNodeToTail(value:Int){
    var node = this
    while (node.next != null) {
        node = node.next
    }
    val newNode= Node(value)
    node.next= newNode

}
fun removeDuplicates (){

    val set = HashSet<Int>()
    var node = this
    set.add(node.value)
    while(node.next != null){
        if (set.contains(node.next?.value)){
            node.next= node.next?.next
        }else{
            set.add(node.next.value)
            node= node.next
        }
    }
}
}
```

In the last two lines:

```
 set.add(node.next.value)
 node= node.next
```

(and in the addNodeToTail method), the compiler says that smart cast is impossible because of complex expression. I have to add non-null asserted call (!!).

I want to understand why this solution is not accepted, although the while expression checks that node.next is not null. And I want to know if there is a better solution than using non-null asserted call (!!).

Thank you for your help

Comment: That's just how Kotlin null safety works. Checking mutable `node.next != null` does not imply it won't be null later as its possible that another thread accesses that node and modifies `next` property. You'd need to create a field that contains `next.value` and refer to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pawel technically answered in the comment.

Basically smart casts are not always possible. In particular, if you define a mutable `var` of nullable type that is technically accessible by multiple threads, the compiler cannot guarantee that the value stays the same between the null check and the usage. That's why you get this error "smart cast impossible".

A common way of dealing with the problem is to store the value in a local `val` variable, to guarantee that this value will not change, and allow the compiler to smart cast it.

In your case though, it's not ideal because the `while` has to check the actual node's value every time. So you'll have to assert that the value is not null at some point, either with `!!` or with an elvis (`?:`) and an `error()` or `throw`.

I would personally go for:

```kotlin
    while (node.next != null) {
        val nextNode = node.next ?: throw ConcurrentModificationException()
        if (set.contains(nextNode.value)) {
            node.next = nextNode.next
        } else {
            set.add(nextNode.value)
            node = nextNode
        }
    }
```

Comment: Mmm.  But you don't even need multiple threads; a value could change as a result of a method call.  (And the compiler can't reasonably check for that; it could be at the end of an arbitrarily-complex sequence of calls, perhaps via code in a library which could be replaced at runtime…)  Storing the value in a local variable (or in the receiver of a scoping function such as `let()`) is a good workaround.

Comment: @gidds true, threads are just an example. But there are cases where there is no method calls, which are easily identifiable by the compiler, and yet it still cannot guarantee anything because of threads. This question of impossible smart case often comes in cases where nothing can happen in the current thread, so people get confused because of that most of the time, hence the example.